# How to make navigation button with Login and Setting title

Tags: iphone, ipad, uibarbuttonitem

I want to add two buttons two navigation bar on right hand side   one for settings and one for login but problem is that only one button i have searched comes on right that is edit is there any other way in which we can make two button and give them desired title.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985839/multiple-barbutton-in-navigation-bar-not-showing-on-ios6?rq=1 i hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *addAttachButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addAttachmentClicked:)];
UIBarButtonItem *sendButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:LS(@"Send") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(sendClicked:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[addAttachButton,sendButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I am using in My UIViewController's implementation file (.m file)

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad{

  [super viewDidLoad];

  //back button
  UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@" Back " style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backTo:)];    


  //Optional: if you want to add space between the back & login buttons
  UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpaceBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace  target:nil action:nil];
           fixedSpaceBarButtonItem.width = 12;

  //login button
  UIBarButtonItem *signIn_BarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@" SIGN IN " style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(signInUser)];            

  //add all buttons to right side
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:backButton, fixedSpaceBarButtonItem,signIn_BarButton, nil];

}
```

now here are the metthods for both button clicks

```
-(IBAction)backTo:(id)sender{

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
}

-(void) signInUser{

    //handle your sigin logic here
}
```

Please! let me if you need more help!

Comment: @ShakeelAhmed for that we need to add buttons in array, see updated answer PL